# MYSQL select function from field value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and its data are mentioned below :

```
id | function
1  | current_date       
2  | UUID()       
3  | RAND()
```

> Structure of the table is
>
> id int, function varchar(50)

Query : select * from func_table;
My excepted result is

```
id | function
1  | 2020-08-24
2  | 70d6cffc-ae01-11ea-80ca-c11529136ae3630       
3  | 0.982584554752
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See about `PREPARE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a giant `case` expression:

```
select (case when function = 'current_date' then cast(current_date as char)
             when function = 'uuid()' then cast(uuid as char)
             when function = 'rand()' then cast(rand as char)
        end) as value
```

If you actually want to *evaluate* the function directly, then you probably have a problem with your data model.  SQL does not directly support such functionality.

Comment: Its good, but I have few functions in the table so it couldn't be a easy way. Anyways Thanks for the support